# is there a way to determine nexus one is dev phone?

Tags: android

I have been given a nexus one by my academic institution and I am developing an application which uses a database on the device.

Unfortunately, I can't view the database on the device despite several attempts.

I tried adb shell, I tried using File Explorer but I can't access the data.

I've asked with my supervisor and he's pretty sure that the device is a dev phone. (I can't really root the phone)

Am I missing something? It's really vital to view the database on the phone otherwise I can't do much testing.

Thanks

Comment: Is there such a thing as a non-rootable phone (that is the same model as one that is rootable)?  Is that what you're calling a "dev phone"?

Answer (score 0):

[Official Android Developer Phones](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) are (to date):

 - Android Developer Phone (ADP)

 - Nexus One

 - Nexus S

Anyway, you can develop in any android-powered phone, so your problem must be elsewhere.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html) you can find a working database example.

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: Yes I can develop, but I can't access the contents of the database on my device. If i access the device with adb shell and then sqlite3 /data/data/package/databases/databasename.db I get access denied

Comment: Have you checked the example that I linked? It's a very basic example using a DataBase, if that doesn't work, maybe there is something wrong with your device.

Comment: I just have. The example doesn't need to *browse* the database manually. By browsing I mean exporting the db file from the databases folder onto my computer and view it using an sqlite3 application.

Comment: Given this is a test application, i suggest you add a custom activity with a text box that sends sql queries to the database and returns the results. This should be the same as you would get with the sqlite command line.